# How would one make it so that I can send a file to a server and then have my python script manipulate it, and then send it back?

Tags: python, flask

Sorry for this really vague question but I am just sort of stuck on how to phrase this question so I haven't really been able to find a proper answer just by googling.

Essentially, I have this python script that alters a csv file in a very specific way. Right now it runs fine on my local machine, but I need this to work with the web. Essentially what I want to be possible is for someone to upload their CSV to my site, it would automatically send to my server, my script would see this, manipulate it in the way necessary, and then send it back once it was finished. Does anyone know any methods of doing this that I should look into?

Again, sorry this is so poorly researched sounding but I am just having a lot of trouble properly phrasing it so I haven't been able to find much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways to make it happen.

### Use synchronous flow

You would upload the file from the browser, that would be handled by the Flask handler, the handler would process the file and return the updated file in the response. Here you can also use polling to poll the server to see if the processing is done or not using ajax along with polling you can use a loader.

**Problem: processing large file, slow internet connection**

### Use asynchronous flow

- You would upload the file from the browser, that would be processed later using some Celery task, other background processor or crontabs that would manipulate the file in the background.
- Post manipulation of the file, you can either give an option in the user profile to download the file, send an email attachment or provide download a link, etc.